# ASP.NET MVC Code first: Multiplicity is not valid in Role in relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a simple relationship. A campaign is linked to two Pages. A page can only be linked to one campaign. But I keep running into this error:

> System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'Page_Campaign_Source' in relationship 'Page_Campaign'. Because the
>   Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound
>   of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

I went looking through some example codes and tutorials while comparing it to my code but I can't find a mistake.

```
 public class Campaign
    {
        [Key()]
        public int Campaignid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Page LandingPage { get; set; }
        public virtual RedeemPage RedeemPage { get; set; }
    }


public class Page
{
    [Key()]
    public int PageContentId { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public string Css { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Campaign")]
    public int campaignID { get; set; }
    public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
}
```

---

### Edit

Followed Eranga's reply and used the Fluent API instead but now I'm getting:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships

Comment: I just wondered, why in the campaign class you have only the virtual objects of the pages and don't have the foreignKey of them, and in the page class you have both the foreignKey and virtual objebt of the campaign?

Comment: Is `RedeemPage` really another class? Or should it be actually `Page`?

Comment: @stmnmn because the foreign key is at the "one"-side of the relation ship

Comment: @Slauma RedeemPage inherits from Page

Comment: Have you tried 'clean and build'? ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data annotations mapping is confusing in this scenario. Use the Fluent API to configure. Remove the data annotations for navigational property mapping and use fluent API as follows.

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Campaign>().HasRequired(x => x.LandingPage)
           .WithMany();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Page>().HasRequired(x => x.Campaign)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.campaignID); 

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

The problem after setting `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` is that both `Campaign` and `Page` has auto incremented PKs and you have a 1-to-1 mapping. Hence to save one record it needs the Id of the other inserted row and that other row need the id of the 1st row.

You can either change the PK to be a GUID or make 1 FK to be nullable and call to `SaveChanges` twice. Eg

Changing the relationship to nullable

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Campaign>().HasOptional(x => x.LandingPage)
       .WithMany();


using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{

       context.Campaigns.Add(campaign);
       context.SaveChanges();

       page.CampaignId = campaign.CampaignId;
       context.Pagess.Add(page);
       context.SaveChanges();

       scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: seems legit, still I'd make an interface or abstract superclass Page.. but don't know the entire context so w/e :p

Comment: I can mix Fluent API with Data annotations right? (so I don't have to redo all my classes)

Comment: @SirTroll You can mix but you may run into problems in some cases when EF gets confused with mappings :)

Comment: @Eranga thanks for helping. Still have some issues, I've updated the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a  collection of pages in your campaign, instead of the 2 children-entities,

has been a while since I've last coded in MVC but if I recall correctly it should be something like:

```
public virtual Collection<Page> pages
```

in which you then put your 2 pages

Comment: Well a Campaign has 2 pages (no more, no less) a regular and a redeem. So I can't use a Collection.

Comment: so you're saying you don't have an interface or abstract superclass? what kind of sourcery is this!?